# Build Android JB for maguro from source

Tags: android, linux, git, android-source, repository

I want to build Android JB for Galaxy Nexus from source. When I execute `lunch` and select *maguro*, I see following:

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.9.99.999.9999.99999
TARGET_PRODUCT=full_maguro
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.2.0-30-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
```

So, I think PLATFORM_VERSION is ICS.

AFAIK I checked out *master*. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest if I open *master* here, I can't understand what platform version it is. How do I find what platform version is in *master* branch?

Comment: Actually, your version is JellyBean. You can read [this tree](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/w2RnhJp3A7s) of discussion. JBQ is a person who you can trust in case of Android :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `build/core/version_defaults.mk`  of your source if the `PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION`  is 16 then it is Jellybean.

A further check would be by comparing current.txt that gets created in the out directory after you build to the `frameworks/base/api/16.txt` . So that the built public apis are same as 16

Edit: Also does the file version_defaults.mk have PLATFORM_VERSION := 4.1.1?

Comment: PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION := 16 and  PLATFORM_VERSION := 4.0.9.99.999.9999.99999